# О смайликах как элементе графики

Tags: общие-вопросы, русская-графика

Вопрос, может, и не имеет отношения к языку, но уж к графике - точно.

Вред ли кого из русских людей надо убеждать, что смайлик типа ))) - это улыбка, а ((( - сожаление.

А если взять скажем араба или японца? Даже не сомневаюсь, что у смайликов будет другая пространственная ориентация, да, собственно, и знаю.

В связи с этим два вопроса. 
1. (для затравки). смайлик "(:" - это улыбка или наоборот?

2. (собственно вопрос). Как объяснить, что для того чтобы распознать эмоцию смайлика бех глахок надо мысленно посмотреть на него против напрвления письма - с конца стпроки - в начало. Казалось бы должно быть наоборот.

Уточняю последнее:

Если у смайлика нет "глазок", то восприятие его зависит от направления письма. Чтобы понять выражаемую эмоцию надо посмотреть на смайлик-скобочку со стороны окончания строки. Или, альтернативно: повернуть лист/экран с текстом так, чтобы начала строк были наверху, а концы - внизу. Это справедливо для всех письменностей. Но при этом взгляд идет как бы **против направления** письма. Странно или это закономерно?

Answer (score 3):

1. Это улыбка.
2. Ничего удивительного. Что в русском, что в латинском алфавите большая часть значимой информации, также как и у эмотиконов находится справа (если закрыть правую или левую половину буквы, то большинство букв легче опознать по правой стороне, тоже самое и со смайлами).

**Добавление:**

Знаки ")" и "(" являются сокращениями от знаков ":-)" и ":-(", улыбка или грусть в них понимается в зависимости от того в какую сторону "смотрит" скобочка в полном эмотиконе.

Comment: Марк Из, Не понимаю, а причем тут "правая" сторона? "("  и ")" ?  Тут хоть на правую стонону смотри, хоть на левую - разницы никакой. Вопрос **откуда** смотреть, с какой стороны. Если наклонить голову налево - одна ситуация, левый смайлик - улыбка, правый - грусть. направо - наоборот. Так вот получается, что мы, "по умолчанию" наклоняем голову налево, арабы - направо. А японцы вообще не наклоняют.

Comment: @behemothus, если у буквы закрыть правую или левую сторону, то опознать ее легче будет по правой стороне. Соответственно, в латинской и кириллической графической системе важные для распознавания знака элементы чаще расположены справа. Тоже самое мы видим и у эмотиконов, где после стандартных **:-** идет ключевой элемент. Думаю это не случайно. В противном случае придется вспомнить ваши же слова о том, что вопрос "почему?" в области языка имеет лишь ответ "так сложилось".

Comment: Марк Из, все равно не понимаю. Вот просто скобочка - (. "закрывать" вообще ничего не надо. Это грусть. Вот другая - ). Это улыбка. Покажи их арабу - будет наоборот. А китаец вообще ничего не увидит скорее всего.

Comment: Мои слова про почему здесь не надо вспоминать. Вопрос как раз предполагает причинно-следственную связь. Я принимаю тезис, что правая часть эмотикона более значима. Я не понимаю, как из этого следует, что "(" - это грусть, а ")" - улыбка (для русского, а для араба - наоборот).

Comment: @behemothus дополнил ответ. О том, что ")" и "(" именно сокращения, читал у Кронгауза в "Самоучителе олбанского", страницу указать не могу, так как в связи с ремонтом доступ к книге проблематичен.

Comment: угу, спасибо. Сейчас попробую вчитаться. У меня голова была другим занята, пардон, что не ответил сразу. Не... все равно не понял. Если сокращения от этих обозначений, то все понятно. Но при чем тогда правая сторона?

Comment: @behemothus, правая сторона - предположение о том, почему изначальные смайлики были повёрнуты в левую сторону.

Comment: а.... В смысле - мордочка глазами влево, ртом - вправо?  Понял. ну вы так из далека заходили... Ладно, плюс уже ваш. Хотя версия user244413 кажется и более естественной и более понятной.